# How do I pass all of the values in a gridrow in a wpf application?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, checkbox, data-binding

I am trying to write a simple application where I display a listview using databinding containing multiple objects that lists their properties and a check box. I let the user check all of the boxes they want removed then press a button that removes the selected elements.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<User> Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("main window");
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Height = "6ft", Checked = false});
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Height = "6ft", Checked = false });
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Height = "5ft", Checked = false });
        drawFolderView();
    }
    private void drawFolderView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = Users;
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Users.Count > 0)
        {
            List<User> itemsToRemove = new List<User>();

            foreach (User person in Users)
            {
                if (person.Checked)
                {
                    itemsToRemove.Add(person);
                }
            }
            foreach (User person in itemsToRemove)
            {
                Users.Remove(person);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("nothing in list");
        }
        drawFolderView();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Height { get; set; }

    public bool  Checked { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(User other) {
        if (Name.Equals(other.Name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

From reading the other questions I made the CheckBox_Checked and Unchecked methods, but I have no idea how to implement them.

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10,10,10,98" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Height" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Height}" />
                <GridViewColumn   Width="60">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Margin="-4,0,-4,0" IsChecked="{Binding MyBoolProperty}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" DataContext="{Binding Checked}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="353,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Many of the concepts surrounding databinding in WPF still confuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checkbox should be changed to this:

```
<CheckBox Margin="-4,0,-4,0" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
```

The DataContext for the Checkbox is the User (like it is for the other columns). The IsChecked property of the Checkbox is bound to the Checked property on the User.

There is no need to call drawFolderView in the button_click method. The lvUsers.ItemsSource is already set to Users. Since Users is an ObservableCollection, it will raise events to tell WPF that items were removed/added and your listview will update itself automatically.

To work best with WPF, your User class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). When the properties of User objects change, your bindings will get updated automatically. Right now, only the listview can change the User objects so you won't get any real benefit from INPC. But, if you added a button that looped through the Users and set User.Checked = true then you would need the INPC interface to tell WPF that the Checked property on the User objects changed so it could update the GUI.

Also, InitializeComponent() should be moved back to the top of the constructor. You only want that called when the window is being created.

Here is an updated version of your code with a few changes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<User> Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Console.WriteLine("main window");
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Height = "6ft", Checked = false });
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Height = "6ft", Checked = false });
        Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Height = "5ft", Checked = false });

        lvUsers.ItemsSource = Users;
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Users.Count > 0)
        {
            List<User> itemsToRemove = new List<User>();

            foreach (User person in Users)
            {
                if (person.Checked)
                {
                    itemsToRemove.Add(person);
                }
            }
            foreach (User person in itemsToRemove)
            {
                Users.Remove(person);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("nothing in list");
        }
    }
}
public class User : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OPC(string propertyName) // OPC = OnPropertyChanged; a helper that raises the PropertyChanged event
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OPC("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age { get { return _age; } set { if (_age != value) { _age = value; OPC("Age"); } } }

    private string _height;
    public string Height { get { return _height; } set { if (_height != value) { _height = value; OPC("Height"); } } }

    private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked { get { return _checked; } set { if (_checked != value) { _checked = value; OPC("Checked"); } } }

    public bool Equals(User other)
    {
        if (Name.Equals(other.Name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, could you recommend any online tutorials to learn more? I have found http://www.wpftutorial.net/ and http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ to be quite lacking

Comment: Syncfusion's free ebook "WPF Succinctly"? https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/wpf